# how to solve complex optimization problem?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-optimization

I have bunch of equations of the form
$$R = V(1) \cdot \cos(\theta) + V(2) \cdot \sin(\theta)$$ with known R and $\theta$ (with measurement errors). With ordinary least squares method, I estimated angle and magnitude of vector $V$. Magnitude of estimated vector seems reasonable where as the angle seem to vary a lot. 
Hence I tried using orthogonal regression to correct the effects of measurement errors on $R$ and $\theta$. The orthogonal regression estimator is then obtained by minimizing,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} (R_{i} - V(1) \cdot \cos(\alpha_{i}) - V(2) \cdot \sin(\alpha_{i}))^{2} + \eta (\theta_{i} - \alpha_{i})^{2}$$ 
where $\alpha$ are the true values of $\theta$ and $\eta$ is ratio of error-variance of R and $\theta$. 
But this a large complex optimization problem with not only two unknown components of vector V but also $\alpha$ (true values of $\theta$). Hence, I am finding it difficult to solve this optimization problem. Please suggest me a method to solve the equation.

Comment: Did you plot these lines to see if there is a reasonable common intersection point ? And is it significantly far from the origin ?

Comment: @Yves Thank you for the reply. These lines don't intersect as there are measurement errors. But, using line-line-Intersection, I could find nearest point to these non-intersecting lines. But this point is optimizing distance and not the angle. And yes they are significantly far from origin.

Comment: If the intersections cluster far from the origin, then your least-square solver must be wrong. There is no reason for $V$ to vary in direction.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAutK.jpg

Comment: @Yves I simulated the problem in matlab. With 10 groups of R and $\theta$, I estimated V.  I repeated it over 1000 times with just varying gaussian noise of 1deg on $\theta$ and 0.1m/s on R. Below is the link for the plot I generated. I wonder why there is so much variation along latitudinal component and very less along longitudinal.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAutK.jpg

Comment: I need to see the lines, not just the $V$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry for late response. I used an online editor to draw these lines, below is the link for the same. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ogfgxkgrqc    I use a simple least square estimator to estimate the intersection point of these lines. In matlab I just use $x = A/b $

Comment: The spread of the intersections shows you the order of magnitude of the accuracy you can expect (which is possibly more important than the point itself !). And your simple estimator seems to give an acceptable result.

Comment: @Yves Yes you are correct, more the spread more is the accuracy. But in my application, I am interested in finding good lateral component than the longitudinal component. This simple estimator is not helping me to good lateral component estimate. So could you suggest any estimator which will help me to do the same?